# mobile redirect with joomla without htaccess

Tags: php, javascript, html, mobile, web

**I have a joomla website,**

1. I am making a mobile site for it .
2. I would like the mobile site to have a "full site" option.

*`When I do this, the redirect kicks in again.  So the mobile user clicks full site, and the full sure is loaded, which has the mobile redirect script, then they get sent back to the mobile site`*.

**Can you guys suggest what I should do?**
Also,

- my mobile site is made by hand,
- It is not a joomla template

So i need it to redirect to a sub folder, not a new joomla template.  And I don't want to use mobile joomla. 
I also have no experience with htaccess
Thanks

Comment: sniff the user agent using `get_browser`

Comment: I have done that, however when the user clicks "full site",  the index where the redirect is gets sniffed again and redirects back to the mobile site.

Comment: send an addition param like`inde.php?full_site=1`

Answer (score 1):

you can make it by a js file.

go on this site, and choose the right method:
http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

you have a lot of choices, you choose the only one you need / prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using PHP.
Try something like this :

```
<?php

$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true) { 
    header('Location: http://mobile.site.com/');
}

?>
```

Comment: What about Windows Phone, Firefox OS, etc?

Comment: It's not an exhaustive list, add strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'Windows Phone') if you want ;)